# How to specify ppk for Git sync operations?

Tags: git, ssh

Is there a way to specify what key to use for Git operations?

Or better yet, is it possible to somehow make Git to use pageant? I tried it, ran pageant and opened a ppk file, but Git does not seem to use it.

Comment: It may help to mention which version of Git you’re running, since Cygwin and msysgit might integrate with your system slightly differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `GIT_SSH` to `plink` which is the command-line part of putty. Then it will use `pageant` if that is already running. The msysGit installer will not do that for you unless you have already been using putty as mentioned in the ReleaseNotes file. If you set GIT_SSH to the TortoiseSvn version of plink it will even raise dialogs for any questions about accepting new keys which avoids you needing to initialize any new connection manually with putty to handle that yourself.